# Problems to include JavaScript together with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

> ```
> <head>
> <script type="text/javascript"
>   src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.0.js"> </script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="future_value.js"> </script> 
>
>  <script>
>   $(document).ready(function()
>   {
>       $("button").click(function()
>       {
>           $("#popup").toggle();
>       });
>   });
> </script>
> ```

I have some jQuery code and some JavaScript code, but I'm not able to run it. It seems like the way I'm including the files is incorrect, because when I delete the JavaScript  tag the jQuery is working fine, and when i delete the JQuery  tag the JavaScript is working.

I'm probably missing something. Thanks

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong... Try removing the space in between both script tags. Also, load jQuery 1.8.1, 1.8.0 had a big bug with IE.

Comment: Note that jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Comment: When you say you're "not able to run it" what do you mean? Do you get JavaScript errors? We'll also need to see the contents of `future_value.js` since that's likely causing the problem.

Comment: error message would help us suggesting the solucation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You files are conflicting. Whoever wrote `future_value.js` is using the `$` as a function in their code. So does jQuery, so they are conflicting with one another. You have a couple options here:

- If future_value.js is short enough, do a search and replace all
  instances of `$` with something like `fv`.
- Use jQuery noConflict  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/ and there after use `jQuery()` instead of `$()` for all your jQuery
  operations

Comment: Sorry, I wrote a question similar to yours. I didn't see that there was a new answar

Comment: No worries ;) our answers are certainly not the same

Comment: @Fresheyeball gr8 i changed all the $ and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the future_value is manipulating with some of jQuery's functions. Try to see if this file is overriding some of jQuery's methods. Example if it does something with `$`.
You could also try to replace `$` with `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

If there's really something messing with the $-variable try this:

```
(function($)
{
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $("button").click(function()
      {
          $("#popup").toggle();
      });
  });
})(jQuery);
```